# A word that means "element", "alloy" and "compound"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that basically means an element, alloy or compound. So if this was the word:

```
pickle (n)
    An element, alloy or compound.
```

Then copper, iron, steel, glass, tin etc... could all be referred to as 'pickles.'

Comment: Isn't glass neither an element, alloy, nor compound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **substance** (b: A material of a particular kind or constitution; AHDEL) may be what you're after.